# Looking for URL scheme (fb://) for the new Facebook iOS 5 app to directly open an image

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios5, ios6

The old URL scheme to open the Facebook app to a particular post does not work with the latest iOS version of the app (released in August 2012).

Under the new scheme, I've figured out how to access events directly with fb://event/eventID and I can access my users' posts via fb://profile/postID.

But how do I access a photo directly if I know the photoID?

Answer (score 3):

From what can be seen in the binary, only the following URLs are recognised:

```
fb://composer?%@
fb://profile
fb://profile?id=%@
fb://album?id=%@
fb://photo?%@
fb://story?%@
fb://messaging?
fb://photo?id=%@
fb://story?id=%@
```

Try fb://photo?id=..

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  Unfortunately, after many attempts the photo scheme above doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code you'll need.

```
fb://photo?id='photoid'&set=a.'albumid.fbid'
```